# Android resource compilation failed in v3.2

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

So I updated my Android Studio to v3.2. When I tried compiling the project, build fails.
Below is the error:

```
Android resource compilation failed
    Output:  C:\Users\Ashish\AndroidStudioProjects\StartUp\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:900: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.

    Command: C:\Users\Ashish\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows.jar\7f1fbe9171e916e5044000cd76b749c8\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
            -o \
            C:\Users\Ashish\AndroidStudioProjects\StartUp\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
            C:\Users\Ashish\AndroidStudioProjects\StartUp\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
    Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

Please do tell if there is any more information required. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate, but this could be what your looking for if your coming fresh here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/56609626/4458638

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I was facing this issue today after updating  gradle from `3.1.4` to `3.2.0`. I don't know why, but the build **started** to throw that exception. i deleted the `build` folder, and deleted the gradle `caches` folder but nothing worked, so i looked at the merged `values.xml` and turns out that my `ids.xml` was defining a wrong id that was being merged to the `values.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="downloading_package" type="id">Baixando pacote de sincronização</item>
</resources>
```

And apparently this was working before the update... for my case i deleted the `ids.xml` file (it was useless in the project)

I wish i could know **why before the update everything was working**

Comment: Yes you are correct!! Turns out the error in `value.xml` was because of the line in `ids.xml`.  I just changed `<item name="action_settings" type="id">action_settings</item>` to `<item name="action_settings" type="id"></item>` and it worked. No need to delete whole `ids.xml` file.

Comment: Hey all, the reason why it worked before was that the incorrect value was ignored. This however could impact the size of the resource table (afaik) and therefore the app, and also lead users to believe in incorrect behaviour (like that you could assign a string to an ID). Now AAPT2 is stricter about it and fails with telling you that you need to remove the value or use a reference to another ID (to match the type).

Comment: In my case, the xml tags having issue exists only workspace.xml in .idea
<item name="cc_entry_internal" type="id">3000</item> what should I do?

Comment: Answer by Ashish Yadav worked for me. The comment was not very clear to I just want to explain that @AshishYadav suggested, editing the ids.xml file and deleting 'action_settings' from the <item name="action_settings" type="id">action_settings</item>

Answer (score 4):

the `<item>` in `values.xml` at line `900` ...might be of resource-type `id`.

the correct syntax would be (just as the error message tells):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item type="id" name="id_name" />
</resources>
```

see the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources#Id).

Comment: Ok but how to change that? Even I change manually and rebuild, it will again make that file the same way.

Comment: @AshishYadav open `values.xml`, goto `line 900` and then remove the content in between `>` and `<`. whatever is being contained there is illegal syntax (and never served any purpose). in case you want to store numbers there, just replace `type="id"` with `type="integer"` (where values are legal).

Comment: Even if I remove it and build it again, it will again comes there and again shows the same error.

Comment: @AshishYadav this comes from cached values of an incremental build (the message reads `build\intermediates\incremental`); `clean` and `rebuild` the project, then this cache should be in order, too.

Comment: @AshishYadav that is non-sense. just delete the `build` directory manually.

Answer (score 3):

For me I had the layout width and layout height in the layout view and the LinearLayout view for databinding. This threw a duplicate error.

I fixed this by removing the `layout_width` and `layout_height` attributes in  `<layout>`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm just finishing this issue a few minutes ago, try to modify or delete id.xml, if you think you don't have it, try to find in another module in your app. I change my value resource from `<item name="header_view" type="id">header_view</item>` to `<item name="header_view" type="id"/>` and it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

just change your attr name which is present in resource -> values -> attr

```
<attr name="fontFamilys">
    <enum name="roboto" value="0" />
    <enum name="roboto_condensed" value="1" />
    <enum name="roboto_slab" value="2" />
</attr>
```

for example if you are getting error related to fontFamily just change the the name build the application error will not come

Answer (score 1):

i also meet the problem,you just need to find where the values in,and update it from `<item type="id" name="id_name" >id_name</item>` to `<item type="id" name="id_name" />`,now it's ok.

Answer (score 1):

I got that problem when I'd quotation within `<string>` tag

```
    <string name="vj_dialogue">I'm waiting</string>
```

when I escaped it with backslash '' . The problem was gone

```
    <string name="vj_dialogue">I\'m waiting</string>
```

Answer (score 1):

This could also happen if you mistakenly happened to not escape some value (apostrophe with backslash or ampersand with & or something else I am not aware of) under res/values/strings.xml file

to bring it in context here is an example ->

incorrect :

```
<string name="update_now">Let's Update now</string>
```

correct  :

```
<string name="update_now">Let\'s Update now</string>
```

Comment: THANK you @puneetyadav! I was just building a project and suddenly got this error for no apparent reason. Then, after reading this post i realized that i had made a string resource with an apostrophe in it!!!

Answer (score 0):

in your build gradle(Project:name) do it like that

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.+'
```

then rebuild your project .. after that it will show message to update your gradle from 4.6 to 4.10

Comment: return it to 3.2.0
and you have to check your ids.xml form any non-char like (' # or something like that)

Answer (score 0):

In my case

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

is repeated twice in the XML. Make sure it should be one per a file at the top of the XML.

Answer (score 0):

**This is what worked for me:**

In my `build.gradle` file > `dependencies`, I was implementing a newer version of  `appcompat` library

```
dependencies {
   implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
   implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'}
```

After commenting `//implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'` It worked fine. I would suggest, even if it's a different library, Please check the version you are using.

Answer (score -1):

In your xml file, you may forget to add `/>` to brace your attribute.