# Android resource linking failed (AAPT2 )

Tags: android, linker, resources, aapt2

Got this Error tried to reinstall Android Studio but this doesn´t work.
Tried to change android support library too but this doesn´t solved the problem either.

```
 Android resource linking failed
    Output:  D:\BKM_Mannesmann_App\FlyAgaricBKM\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:18: error: resource font/advent_pro_light (aka com.example.andre.flyagaricbkm:font/advent_pro_light) not found.
    error: failed linking references.

    Command: C:\Users\Andre\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\81df7b1db56f260e308cf68da520606d\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
            E:\androidsdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar\
            --manifest\
            D:\BKM_Mannesmann_App\FlyAgaricBKM\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
            -o\
            D:\BKM_Mannesmann_App\FlyAgaricBKM\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
            -R\
            @D:\BKM_Mannesmann_App\FlyAgaricBKM\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
            --auto-add-overlay\
            --java\
            D:\BKM_Mannesmann_App\FlyAgaricBKM\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
            --custom-package\
            com.example.andre.flyagaricbkm\
            -0\
            apk\
            --output-text-symbols\
            D:\BKM_Mannesmann_App\FlyAgaricBKM\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
            --no-version-vectors
    Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52503768/android-resource-compilation-failed-in-v3-2

Comment: You're referencing a resource named 'advent_pro_light' with type 'font'. Do you have it defined anywhere in your resources?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I made two custom backgrounds which were not recognised.

I removed the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` tag from the top of those two XML resources file.

This worked for me, after trying many solutions from the community.