# Getting resource compilation failed after Android Studio updated to 3.2.1

Tags: android, logcat

Getting Android resource compilation failed after Android Studio updated to 3.2.1 
Gradle Version: 3.3.0
Getting the below error in message view

Android resource compilation failed
E:\AndroidProjects\OnlineMP3\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:595: error:  inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.
E:\AndroidProjects\OnlineMP3\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:596: error:  inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.
E:\AndroidProjects\OnlineMP3\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:597: error:  inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android resource compilation failed in v3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52503768/android-resource-compilation-failed-in-v3-2)

Comment: <item name="player_display" type="id">player_display</item>
    <item name="player_display_box" type="id">player_display_box</item>
    <item name="player_display_float_box" type="id">player_display_float_box</item>

Comment: this is illegal... `id` resources must not have a value; just as logcat says.

Comment: What's the possible fix .?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provided code here. As per the log, I can suggest you. When you declare id in resources, body should be empty. for ex.

```
<item
    type="id"
    name="id_name" />
```

For more info refer below link
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources#Id

Comment: can not edit the values.xml file as it as build file